# How to assign values to properties while creating object to a class in php?

Tags: php

I have a xml data stored in `$string` like this

```
<DATA>
<STOREITEMS>
  <CREATED date="Tue Oct 9 5:30:01 BST 2012">
    <CATEGORY id="442" name="Hen And Stag Nights"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="69" name="Games"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="252" name="Love Zone"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="202" name="Spotlight  Items"></CATEGORY>
  </CREATED>
  <CREATED date="Wed Oct 10 5:30:01 BST 2012">
    <CATEGORY id="442" name="Hen And Stag Nights"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="69" name="Games"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="252" name="Love Zone"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="202" name="Spotlight  Items"></CATEGORY>
  </CREATED>
</STOREITEMS>
<DATA>
```

php code

```
class Detail
{
    public $Id;
}

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$result = $xml->xpath('//DATA/STOREITEMS/CREATED');

foreach ($result as $node) {

              $dta = new Detail($Id = $node['date']);
              //Dont know this is correct or not
              //but need to assign values while creating object                       
}


$json= json_encode($dta );
echo $json;
```

I need to assign `$node['key']` value to the `$Id` property of class Detail

Simply `$dta` should hold two objects with two `$id` values inserted

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a __construct function

```
class Detail{
    public $Id;

    public function __construct($id){
        $this->Id = $id;    
    }
}
$detail = new Detail('1');
var_dump($detail->Id);
```

Comment: there are two $node['date'] values. So i need to get two objects of class Detail with two Id 's right ?

Comment: @Cashew yes. according to your code, i think it was better to just put date values into array and then json_encode,like this: foreach($result as $node){$date_info[] = $node['date'];} json_encode($date_info);

Comment: Wow ! thats what i want .Thanks bro